# Peer to peer message relay using Multipeer Connectivity

Tags: ios, titanium, multipeer-connectivity

I am creating an application that uses the Multipeer Connectivity framework provided by iOS 7.
I was able to successfully transmit messages from devices connected over only bluetooth in a network with messages but what I need to do is to relay a message over .

Say for example Device A,Device B and Device C are connected with each other over Bluetooth while Device A moves away to a distance where it can only see Device B in range but not Device C and wants to send a message over?

I have written the code for message relay which successfully sends message from Device A to Device C via device B but right now it is only happening when all 3 devices are connected in the network,when device A moves away it completely loses B and C from range. I am unable to create a network where A is connected to B while B is connected to C and A and B are not connected. So Unable to test the code properly.Any inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't have enough devices to test this. Do they all stay on the same session? I would think that if they are on the same session, the framework should do this automatically; but if not, then you'll need to make multiple sessions and implement your own mesh network… I'd like to know how the guys from the FireChat app implemented this.

Comment: @NiñoScript :How to go about implementing a mesh of that kind is what I am stuck at,I did the application logic of what needs to be done if the peer isnt available but I am not able to setup a network that would help my code work. :(

Comment: @NiñoScript : I have tested the firechat applications nearby feature which doesn't seem to be relaying any message as such to a peer who has lost connectivity with other peers once moved out of range.